# Android app size continues to increase after adding Adview

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, admob, google-play-services, application-size

My App consists of a main **ViewPager** Fragment and an **Adview** which is inserted on main FragmentActivity layout. (I use **Google Play Services** for the ad.)

The weird problem is that just after adding Adview, upon each switch between different FragmentActivities, the App size (Settings> Apps >App info> STORAGE> Data) increases by about 100kB.

To be sure about all other interferring reasons I already disabled SQLite database and SharedPrefrences, but I still have the same problem.

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this @Ossen?  I have the exact same problem, the storage keeps increasing with every launch.  If I turn off my network connection so no ads are served, the issue goes away.  I'm not using the AdMob SDK though although am using AdMob through mediation.... chreers

Comment: I added an Storage Management option to my app in order that user can erase this while keeping SQLite. By chance did you activate backup option within the Manifest of your app?

Comment: Hi @Ossen, Yeah, I have enabled the Backup option.  Is this what is causing it?  Mine seems to be caused (for the most part) by the MobFox  SDK, they sent me an update and it has somewhat mitigated the problem, but it's still there :-(